# Finding the width and height of a bmp image using bitwise operators

Tags: c++, image, bmp

Hello I am try to find the width and the height of a BMP image using only bitwise operators.
This is what I have tried so far.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        width = file_data[i + 18] | width << 8;
        height = file_data[i + 22] | height << 8;
    }
```

This is what I know.  The width is found in bytes 19, 20, 21 and 22.  Byte 19 is the low order byte followed by 20 then 21 and byte 22 which is the high order byte.

The height the height is found in bytes 23, 24 25 and 26. Byte 23 is the low order byte followed by 24 then 25 and byte 26 which is the high order byte.

width and height are ints.

Update--------
the width and height of the file im currently working with is 298 by 432
when I use

```
 for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        width = file_data[21 - i] | width << 8;
        height = file_data[25 - i] | height << 8;
    }
```

when I run the program i get 298 by -80

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Copy the data into a BITMAPINFO structure and access the fields directly.

Comment: I want to practice with bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is backwards, although your description is correct. `file_data[18]` is the least significant byte of the width of the bitmap, but you are placing it as the most significant byte in your `width` variable. Same goes for the `height`. Either reverse the loop to count down, or change your indexing to subtract instead of add.

Comment: I tried that width = file_data[21 - i] | width << 8; height = file_data[25 - i] | height << 8; It doesn't work

Comment: @john: What is the type of `width`, `height` and `binary_data`? Better yet, in your post, please provide a complete, compileable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: sorry I was thinking and typing its file_data the data that was in the file. width and height are ints.

Comment: @john: Okay, none the less, I will need to see a complete, compileable example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: alright here is something weird. I am getting correct output for other bmp files but for this one I am now not getting correct height. the width is now fine its just the height.

Comment: @john: Can't help you. I've already told you twice what I need to see.